# SVN error 155009: Failed to run the WC DB work \ Can't open file \ The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: svn

I found [poor info](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=%22Failed%20to%20run%20the%20WC%20DB%20work%20queue%20associated%20with%22%20%22Can%27t%20open%20file%22%20%22The%20system%20cannot%20find%20the%20file%20specified%22) with svn Error `155009` with message:

> Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with 'C:\Users\XXX\Foo',
>   work item 82 (file-install Bar.dll 1 0 1 1) Can't open file
>   'C:\Users\XXX\Foo.svn\pristine\c2\c2dbd0fd0b44d0e4915581196479ada5567b0750.svn-base':
>   The system cannot find the file specified

I'm on Windows 7 with 1.8.11 svn libs (installed by Tortoise).

Help me to understand the problem and how fix it when happen..

Answer (score 2):

The pristine area of the working copy is corrupted.  There is a great chance that some tool or an antivirus broke the pristine area.

Make a backup of the contents of this working copy and checkout a new working copy.