# Clean up working copy which has a deleted file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My SVN repo is running into problems when updating. It's complaining that I should clean it up ("Previous operation did not finish").
I ran the cleanup in the root folder and selected the checkboxes [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35192644/480982).
During the clean up process, it reports the following failure:

```
Cleanup failed to process the following paths:
B:\xxx
Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with
'B:\xxx', work item 17399 (file-install 60 .../SniffPass.exe 1 0 1 1)
Can't open file
'B:\xxx\.svn\pristine\42\424...b0e.svn-base':
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The mentioned file probably does not exist any more because the virus scanner deleted it, since it contained a copy of the NirSoft SniffPass tool which was considered dangerous.
It is not dangerous to me, since I know this repository contains all sorts of debugging and security tools. I have now excluded the directory from virus scanning.

I accidentally found the missing file in a backup copy and putting it into the expected place solves the issue. That's great so far.

However, this issue happens with several other files as well.

How would I repair this repo and restore all the missing files? Neither the cleanup process nor the update process will simply download it. I'd not like to clone the entire repo [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474848/svn-error-155009-failed-to-run-the-wc-db-work-cant-open-file-the-system-ca), since it's 11 GB in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, your virus scanner removed a file from the working area (`B:\xxx`) and from the pristine area (`B:\xxx\.svn\pristine\`). You can try restoring all the removed files from backup. If they are missing in backup, then I don't think there is an easy way to manually repair your working copy.

I would recommend checking out a fresh working copy and exclude it from antivirus scanning.

Comment: You mean I should copy all the `.svn\pristine` files from the backup to the SVN? Or how would I find out which files are missing? SVN needs 2 operations `svn update` and `svn cleanup` to report one missing file

Comment: @ThomasWeller 1. create a copy of your current SVN working copy (the one which is corrupt). This is needed as a precaution to ensure that you don't make things worse. 2. copy all contents of B:\xxx\.svn\ from backup atop the .svn directory in the new working copy. Run `svn cleanup` when copy is complete.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't really go well. I copied all the `.svn\pristine` files first (~9000), just to find out that it complains about files in the working directory next. I also copied those, but in the end is still downloaded ~900 MB from the server. I don't think it was worth all the effort and I should simply have checked out the repo over night again.